# Generalisation of the fact that smallest prime index subgroups are normal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am struggling with this, a **hint** is very much appreciated!

*Let $G$ be a group of order $rt$, such that $r\leq p$ for every prime factor $p$ of $t$. If there exists $H$ subgroup of $G$ of index $r$, then $H$ is normal.*

Comment: Feels like it might have to use Sylow's theorem(s).

Comment: Hint: Consider another subgroup of the same order as $H$. What can the size of the product of these subgroups be?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How do you define the product? Usually, for the product of two subgroups, one has to be normal...

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Though the argument does work...

Comment: @Igor For the product to be a subgroup we need that. The product is always a subset, and the size is always given by the same formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof:** (To my question)

$H$ is a subgroup of order $t$. Let $K$ be some other subgroup of order $t$. Then:
$$ |HK| = \dfrac{t^2}{|H\cap K|} \leq rt, $$ which implies that 
$$ \dfrac{t}{|H\cap K|} \leq r. $$ If the left side is bigger than one, then by hypothesis $r$ is equal to the smallest prime factor of $|G|$, and by the particular case of the theorem we have that $H$ is normal. Otherwise, $t=|H\cap K|$ and $H=K$ so that $H$ is unique and hence normal. $\square$

Comment: Very nice, exactly the proof I had in mind. Though note that what you need for this from the lemma is in fact the easy direction, which does not even have any requirements on the order and index.

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot.